# Selecting duplicates items with NHibernate IQueryOver

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate, queryover

I'am using NHibernate `3.3.1.4000` and FluentNHibernate `1.3.0.733` for SQL Server 2012 and IQueryOver

I have next classes:

```
class Foo {
  public virtual int Id;
  public virtual Bar Bar;
  public virtual Baz Baz;
}
class Bar {
  public virtual int Id;
}
class Baz {
  public virtual int Id;
}
```

I want to select all `Foo` entites, which contains same `Bar` and `Baz` children.
I know how to do this theoretically by LINQ query (IQueryable)

```
IList<Foo> fooData = Session.Query<Foo>.GroupBy(x => x, new DistinctItemComparer()).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key).ToList();

class DistinctItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo> 
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return (x.Id == y.Id) || ((x.Bar.Id == y.Bar.Id) && (x.Baz.Id == y.Baz.Id)); 
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Bar.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Baz.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

but I got error:

> Could not parse expression 'value(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Foo]).GroupBy(x => x, value(DistinctItemComparer))': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy' is currently not supported.

So, maybe there are other solutions exist (with `IQueryOver`, maybe?) to get duplicates entries. Not drop them and receive distinct. I want exact only duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var fooData = (from foo1 in Session.Query<Foo>()
               from foo2 in Session.Query<Foo>()
               where foo1.Id != foo2.Id 
                     && foo1.Bar.Id == foo2.Bar.Id 
                     && foo1.Baz.Id == foo2.Baz.Id
               select foo1).Distinct().ToList();
```